# how to open a window from a window exist

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a main window, inside there is a button which in a click- 
open a dialog window to write a name save a name in a textbox and need to open another window.

I want it will open the new window at the main window- 
but it is opened the window in the dialog window, allthoght I set the Owner to be the main window..

what should I do?

this is the code in a button of the dialog window:

```
 Screen myScreen = new Screen (name, ViewModel, mainWindow);
 myScreen.Owner = mainWindow;
 myScreen.Show();
 this.Close();
```

Comment: So, you want to open a Dialog from a Dialog?

Comment: Try after removing  myScreen.Owner = mainWindow;....I dont think any issue with the code

Comment: I want to open  Screen window- in the window that was of the mainMenu, and to do this from the dialog I opened from the mainMenu @Pikoh

Comment: Well...You can´t, you should close your first dialog before showing the second

Comment: Close the existing dialog, and then open the new one from main window.

Comment: but I need the name from the textBox- in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

In your first dialog, you must have a public variable,something like:

```
public string TextBoxContent;
```

And in the OK button event, you'll do something like:

```
this.TextBoxContent = TextBox.Text;
this.DialogResult = true;
this.Close();
```

In your main window you must do this:

```
string returnedString;
DialogWindow w = new DialogWindow ();
w.ShowDialog();
if (w.DialogResult.HasValue && w.DialogResult.Value)
     returnedString=w.TextBoxContent;
```

And after that, you'll show your second dialog with the returned string. Hope you see the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have three windows one is `MainWindow` which have a button to open another window name `Dialog` which have a `textBox` for input name and a button for pass that `textBox` input to another window name `Screen`. SO I have take a `textBox` in `Screen` window named `textBoxName` which will show the passed text, here is my solution

the main window button show dialog this way

```
 private void buttonMainShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dialog dl = new Dialog();
            dl.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Constructor for `Screen` window as below which take text as a parameter by which we pass the `Dialog` window `textBox` text

```
 public Screen(string text)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.textBoxName.Text = text;
        }
```

and you need to call this screen window from dialog window as below

```
 private void buttonDialogShowScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Screen myScreen = new Screen(this.textBox.Text);
            myScreen.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

its works fine, hope this help you

Comment: You are showing the forms as non-modal. The OP wants the windows to be shown as Dialogs.

Comment: No, it won't work. `Screen` should be shown also as a Dialog. Once you call `myScreen,ShowDialog()`, you wouldn't be able to close the first Dialog

Comment: but @ABC is not asking that `Screen` also will be dialog

Comment: Well,I think he is because otherways it's a nonsense to set Dialog owner,but you are right in his code he calls `myScreen.Show();`. It's not very clear :)

Comment: actually he want something else see @Roma s comment discussion but he didn't ask correct way

Comment: O.k., now I see. That was impossible to see reading his question :)